# Emacs: How to enable toolbar mode and menubar mode only under a certain mode?

Tags: emacs

I use Emacs. However, I am not familiar with Lisp although I do know some functional programming, and hence I never really understood how to customize the `init.el`.

So basically, I want to be able to enable the toolbar mode and menubar mode only if I am in `R-mode`.

I know that to enable these mode simply requires:

`(tool-bar-mode 1)` and `(menu-bar-mode 1)`

but what if I want to do this locally, i.e. enable them only if I am in `R-mode`.

What should I put in the `init.el` ?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible with this advice:

```
(defadvice select-window (after select-window-change-menubar activate)
  (let ((yes-or-no
         (if (memq major-mode '(r-mode lisp-interaction-mode))
             1 -1)))
    (menu-bar-mode yes-or-no)
    (tool-bar-mode yes-or-no)))
```

I added two modes to the list for now, `lisp-interaction-mode` is the
mode of the `*scratch*` buffer, so that it's easy to test if the
advice works.

It's super-annoying, but kind of cool at the same time. I hope it's
what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The features I describe here are close to what you are asking, but not an exact match.  If your real need is to not have the tool bar around all the time when you don't need it, then they might help.

Library [**Tool-Bar+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToolBar#ToolBarPlus) provides two possibilities that limit when a tool bar is shown:

1. **`tool-bar-here-mode`**:

   Enable the tool bar for specific frames only.  Presences or absence of the tool bar is a frame thing, not a window or buffer/mode thing.  When present, the actual contents of the tool bar (its icons) are specific to the selected window and its buffer.  But whether or not the tool bar is shown has to do with the frame.

   You enable showing the tool bar for the selected frame with command `tool-bar-here-mode`.  You can add this to a mode hook, so that when a given mode is enabled so is the tool bar:

   ```
      (add-hook 'info-mode (lambda () (tool-bar-here-mode 1)))
   ```

   But that does not turn the mode off when the same frame no longer shows a buffer with that mode.  In this regard it does not answer your question exactly.
2. **`tool-bar-popup-mode`**:

   Hide the tool bar, and just put a **`Buttons`** entry in the menu-bar. When you click it the tool bar pops up for a single tool-bar action.  So:

   a. Click `Buttons` - the tool-bar pops up.

   b. Click a tool-bar icon to effect its action - then the tool bar is hidden again.

Answer (score 0):

For the toolbar, you can bind it to one of your mouse buttons or a key-sequence. For example, try this in your .emacs file:

```
(global-set-key [mouse-8] 'tool-bar-here-mode)
(tool-bar-pop-up-mode 1)
```

Depending on your mouse, you'll need to change 'mouse-8' to reflect the mouse button you wish to bind to. (Hint, click your desired mouse button while Emacs has the focus and you will see a message at the bottom like:

is undefined

Alternatively, you can bind to a key on your keyboard, like for instance:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") 'tool-bar-here-mode)
```

which will bind it to the CTRL-.